# How to get a bytearray from file stream in Adobe AIR?

Tags: flash, file, actionscript, air, arrays

I read limited (small - 15 - 500 mb files).
I need to be able to put all file bytes into one single bytearray.
So I have a function:

```
        [Bindable]
        public var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
        //.... code ....//
        protected function fileOpenSelected(event:Event):void
        {
            currentFile = event.target as File;
            stream = new FileStream();
            stream.openAsync(currentFile, FileMode.READ);
            stream.readBytes(ba);
            stream.close();

                            MyFunction(ba);
        }
```

But it does not work=( - gives me Error: Error #2030: End of file was encountered.

How to get a full bytearray from stream to use it as normal bytearray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isn't the point of a `FileStream` that you don't have a normal `ByteArray`, but read asynchronously? It implements [`IDataInput`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/IDataInput.html), allowing you to read from it as long as `bytesAvailable` is bigger than 0.

on every progress event, you can just `readBytes` into an output `ByteArray` and once you get a complete event, you can use it.

greetz
back2dos

Comment: but I want my bytaarray( - my class uses it!)

Comment: well, either you use the approach I described or you try `File::load()` and then access `File::data`

Comment: Downvoted because, either you're describing the old method of waiting for an event.complete and passing the data to an event handler, or this was worded quite confusingly. It should be a snap to grab a ByteArray from a FileStream (and some of us do indeed need that.)

Answer (score 5):

I finally figured this out, after looking through the documentation for a good while. Whew!

In my case, I was having to read a wav file as a bytesArray for a class I was using, so I could use it on demand at the public scope.

```
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("blip.wav");
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray
fileStream.readBytes(bytes);
fileStream.close();
```

Hope this helps you as much as it helped me. I've tested it and confirmed that it works.

Comment: shouldn't it be  `new ByteArray()`

Comment: I've been away from AS3 since Nov 2014, but I know this ran as expected. Also, I know that you omit the parenthesis from an empty constructor call in C++, though I can't remember if that rule carried over to AS3.